# Check box is not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I know this is asked a million times here, but I am not getting it for the life of me.  I have a checkbox in a php page with code as such:

```
CODE UPDATED BELOW
```

This is a simple on/off switch.  It should send the value of checked or not to the php form onff-switch.php so that form can post to a MySql table with this code: [UPDATED]

```
CODE UPDATED BELOW
```

The first concern is that I am getting errors via terminal if I use the $con.  It tells me there are syntax errors, even though I have double checked it with w3schools.com.

That aside, when the box is checked, then the value should be ON, if not checked, then value is OFF and it should be UPDATEd in the database table.

UPDATE: I have moved all elements to one single page as seen below, but there is still no posting to the database:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASS","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
    // escape variables for security
    $scanningvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['onoffswitch']);

    $sqlon="INSERT INTO configuration (scanning) VALUES ('$scanningvalue')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sqlon);
    if($scanningvalue=='') $scanningvalue='off';
       if($result)
    {
       echo "The db operation done (1 record added) and switch value ".$scanningvalue;
    }
else
{
   echo "The db operation error and switch value ".$scanningvalue;
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" 
               name="onoffswitch" 
               class="onoffswitch-checkbox" 
               id="myonoffswitch" 
               value="on"
              checked
               >
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Where is an html element named as 'on' or 'off'

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis at the end. Must be like this `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","config","password","mysql_db");`

Comment: input fields extracted by value... that's what w3schools can teach you...

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
$scanningonoff = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['onoffswitch']);

$sqlon="INSERT INTO configuration (scanning) VALUES ('$scanningon')";
```

Typos -

```
1) $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","config","password","mysql_db"));
                                                                  ^ extra bracket

2)   if (isset($_POST['onoffswitch'])) {
        {                              ^  extra bracket
         mysqli_query($con,$sqlon);
        }
    else {
        mysqli_query($con,$sqloff);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Db Connection thing, you are putting double brackets at the end. Remove it

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","config","password","mysql_db");
```

You call the element by its name not by its value, so it will be 'onoffswitch' while retrieving the data using $_POST call

```
$scanningonoff = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['onoffswitch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","config","password","mysql_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
// escape variables for security
$scanningvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['onoffswitch']);

$sqlon="INSERT INTO configuration (scanning) VALUES ('$scanningvalue')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sqlon);
if($scanningvalue=='') $scanningvalue='off';
if($result)
{
   echo "The db operation done (1 record added) and switch value $scanningvalue";
}
else
{
   echo "The db operation error and switch value $scanningvalue";
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: ok question is, is the checkbox form sending the value correctly?

Comment: php onoff-switch.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/onoff-switch.php on line 25

Comment: found it, was line 24

Comment: ok php form seems to be error free but the HTML form does not seem to be sending a value to the php form.  When ever I check or uncheck, there is no change

Comment: this code is almost correct, but the $con still causes an error.  In fact the feedback I get is "The db operation error and switch value ".$scanningvalue  which also states that the value of $scanningvalue is Off.  Who knows where that came from....

Comment: normally localhost username "root" and password "" (null)

Comment: no not really.  the user can be any user with access

Comment: if wamp , then place both html and php file in www folder

Comment: both are located in the web root

Comment: do one thing, both html and php content in same page and make form action=''. add connection before html content, then check form posting or not...

Comment: No luck.  When I do it all on one page, it does nothing.  The checkbox functions but no posting to MySql: